# How to customize jquery validation number format?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I want to set jQuery validation to consider as valid decimal point and not comma (0.5 <- not valid, 0,5 <- valid). How can I achieve this?

Edit:

I use ASP.NET MVC 4 form:

I have some field with float type in model.

I have for these fields Html helper editors.

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OverRunningClutch.D2)
```

The framework automatically do a lot of things (like client side validation with jquery validation). But the ASP.NET DefaultModelBinder does not parse the fields in the format that has the decimal point. But if I type with comma, the jquery validation say it is not valid.

Comment: Please show us your existing validation code.

Answer (score 0):

The long, complete and really interesting answer is in [Globalization, Validation and Date/Number Formats in Asp.Net MVC](http://www.dotnet-programming.com/post/2011/12/14/Globalization-Validation-and-DateNumber-Formats-in-AspNet-MVC.aspx)

For a Q&D short answer, you may go for something like :

```
var genuineNumberFunc = $.validator.methods.number;
$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
 if(value.indexOf(',')!=-1)
      return false;
 return genuineNumberFunc(value, element);
}
```